# Back button takes the view to initial page from tags search

Tags: bug, android-app

Here is what I do:

1. Search for a tag
2. Open a discussion from list of discussions returned by search result
3. Tap back button

This should take the view to search result but instead it returns back to tags search.

I believe this behaviour to be a bug and it is unpleasant to search for your tag every time.

- App Version: 1.0.85
- Device Manufacturer: asus
- Device Model: ASUS_Z00AD
- OS Version: 5.0 (WW_Z00A-WW_2.20.40.139_20151104_2652_user_rel-user-20151104)

Comment: Okay. I get that its a duplicate bug report but shouldn't it have been closed by now? Anyone can tell me where can i see the status for this bug fix.